# How to check if String[] contains my element?

Tags: java, arrays

I've been asked to write a code that adds elements to an array with a few conditions. I've searched all over StackOverflow to find out how to find an element in an array but all give me errors, so I'm guessing it's something wrong with my code and I can't figure out what. Any help is appreciated.

```
public class WordList
{
    String [] words;
    int count = 0;
    int max = 2;

    WordList()
    {
        words = new String[max];
        this.words = words;
        this.count = count;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        WordList w1 = new WordList();
        System.out.println(w1.addWord("Dog"));
        System.out.println(w1.addWord("Cat"));
        System.out.println(w1.addWord("Fish"));
    }

    public int addWord(String newWord)
    {

        for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++)
        {
            if(words.contains(newWord) == false && words.length < max)
            {
                words[i] = newWord;
            }
            else if(words.contains(newWord) == false && words.length == max)
            {
                max *= 2;
                words[i] = newWord;
            }



            count = i + 1;
        }
        return count;
    }
```

Comment: If you get an error message, please share it

Comment: you can not call a method on an arry, i guess you want to use an `ArrayList` https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/array-vs-arraylist-in-java/

Comment: I think what you need are ArrayLists... Default Arrays, dont have those nice methods.
https://beginnersbook.com/2013/12/java-arraylist/

Comment: `max *= 2;` just FYI, this won't change the size of the array. You'll also need to reallocate it.

Comment: Because String[] words will not have that method. please use any collection

Answer (score 2):

I think you could use `Set` instead of array.

```
public class WordList {

    private final Set<String> words = new HashSet<>();

    public int addWord(String word) {
        if (word != null)
            words.add(word);
        return words.size();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WordList w1 = new WordList();
        System.out.println(w1.addWord("Dog"));
        System.out.println(w1.addWord("Cat"));
        System.out.println(w1.addWord("Fish"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're trying to do. Regular arrays dont have an `indexOf` or `contains` method so you need to use `Arrays` (make sure you import it too)

```
public int addWord(String newWord)
{
  List <String> myList = Arrays.asList(words);

    for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++)
    {
        if(myList.indexOf(newWord) == -1 && words.length < max)
        {
            words[i] = newWord;
        }
        else if(myList.indexOf(newWord) == -1 && words.length == max)
        {
            max *= 2;
            words[i] = newWord;
        }

        count = i + 1;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Why every time convert the Array to a list? It has a better Performance if op uses the List in the complete program

Comment: @jens You're right.

Answer (score 0):

In Any way you'll need to write your own method to find it. It you are not limited with memory - you can convert array to List and use .contains() method.

```
Arrays.asList(words).contains(newWord);
```

Otherwise you may use stream to find the element.

```
Arrays.stream(words).anyMatch(newWord::equals);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a solution something like this, but this is using `ArrayList` and not `Array`. Arrays do not have default `contains` method and you would need to implement your own method.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class WordList {
    private static List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addWord(String word) {
        if (!words.contains(word)) {
            words.add(word);
        }
    }

    public static List<String> getWords() {
        return words;
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        WordList instance = new WordList();
        instance.addWord("Dog");
        instance.addWord("Cat");
        instance.addWord("Fish");

        System.out.println(instance.getWords());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Error was in `words.contains(newWord)`

> cannot find symbol   symbol:   method contains(String)   location:
>   variable words of type String[]

It could resolve by change code -

`Arrays.asList(words).contains(newWord)` instead of `words.contains(newWord)`.

Remember you will need to import `java.util.Arrays`

Full code -

```
import java.util.Arrays;

/**
 *
 * @author pronet
 */
public class WordList
{
    String [] words;
    int count = 0;
    int max = 2;

    WordList()
    {
        words = new String[max];
        this.words = words;
        this.count = count;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        WordList w1 = new WordList();
        System.out.println(w1.addWord("Dog"));
        System.out.println(w1.addWord("Cat"));
        System.out.println(w1.addWord("Fish"));
    }

    public int addWord(String newWord)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++)
        {
            if(Arrays.asList( words ).contains(newWord) == false && words.length < max)
            {
                words[i] = newWord;
            }
            else if(Arrays.asList( words ).contains(newWord) == false && words.length == max)
            {
                max *= 2;
                words[i] = newWord;
            }
            count = i + 1;
        }
        return count;
    }
 }
```

Hope it could help you.

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class WordList {

    private final Set<String> words = new HashSet<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WordList w1 = new WordList();
        System.out.println(w1.addWord("Dog"));
        System.out.println(w1.addWord("Cat"));
        System.out.println(w1.addWord("Fish"));
    }

    public int addWord(String word) {
        words.add(word);
        return words.size();
    }

}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.